# Merge SQL Columns & Data with same prod_id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| id   | product | prod_id |
| 1001 | Item 1  | P1001   |
| 1002 | Item 2  | P1001   |
| 1003 | Item 3  | P1003   |
```

My desired output is:

```
| id   | prod_id        |
| 1001 | Item 1, Item 2 |
| 1003 | Item 3         |
```

As you can see, Item 1 and 2 has the same prod_id.

This is what I tried:

`select id, prod_id from table_name where prod_id = product;`

Basically what I tried was to merge all the products with the same prod_id and then just display them as id & prod_id.

I am new to mySQL and would love some feedback on how I can do this. I am not sure if my logic is correct in trying to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use aggregate function `MIN` with `GROUP_CONCAT`

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  id int,
  product varchar(50),
  prod_id varchar(50)
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES (1001,'Item 1','P1001');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1002,'Item 2','P1001');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1003,'Item 3','P1003');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT MIN(id) id,GROUP_CONCAT(product) prod_id        
FROM T
GROUP BY prod_id;

| id   | prod_id       |
| ---- | ------------- |
| 1001 | Item 1,Item 2 |
| 1003 | Item 3        |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pwy7T93aHfFfnQa9eGwRys/0)

Comment: and in case you want to incorporate the id into the group you can extend the `GROUP CONCAT` to `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(product, " (", id, "("))`

Comment: D-Shih, this is the perfect answer! Thank you for teaching me about the `GROUP_CONCAT`. I'll go study on it. And yes, I tried what you posted and it works exactly the way I need it to be. I'll mark your answer correct in 2 mins when it allows me to. Thank you D-Shih.

Comment: @gosi123 No problem glad to help you :)